# Indefinite sum in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, geometric-series

> $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2}\right)^n$$

Obviously it is a geometric series with an index shift. So I got:

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2}}-\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{2}{2-\mathrm{i}}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{10-\mathrm{i}}{8-4i}$$

I've checked this solution with WA, but it's wrong (Correct solution: $-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{\mathrm{i}}{10}$).

Any hints?

Comment: $$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} x^n = x^2\cdot \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n = \Biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n\Biggr) - 1 - x$$

Comment: Shouldn't you be subtracting off the $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ terms, instead of the $n = 2$ term?

Comment: For $|z|<1$ $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty z^n=\dfrac{z^k}{1-z}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you did is right except subtraction. U should subtract i/2 and 1  instead of (i/2) square

Answer (score 2):

If break down summations into two part real and imaginary:

$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\frac{i}{2})^n$, break this into two infinite sums.

1) case $n=2k$: $S_1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{2^2})^k=\frac{-1}{5}$

2) case $n=2k+1$: $S_2=\frac{i}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{2^2})^k=\frac{-1}{5}\frac{i}{2}$

then $S=S_1+S_2$.

Thanks to @lisyarus, for the explanation. 
However, the answer is still true but more complicate. 
Without complicating computations we can use general formula for power series $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x^k}{1-x}\Leftrightarrow ||x||<1$$

Comment: "We always need to break down summations into two part real and imaginary:" - false, there is no point in doing this in general. The formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series is valid in any Banach algebra, including complex numbers.

Comment: @lisyarus: So, you did not understand $\mathbb{C}$ and geometric sums.

Comment: The result can be obtained via the general formula, without any breaking into sums:  $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^n = \frac{\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^2}{1-\frac{i}{2}} = -\frac{1}{4}\frac{1+{i\over 2}}{1+{1\over 4}}=-\frac{1+{i\over 2}}{5}$

Comment: Also, saying that someone does not understand something in not constructive. If you think someone is wrong, provide agruments saying where exactly is he wrong.

Comment: The formula for power series is true (converges) only if we have $\abs(x)<1$. Now what is the $\abs{\frac{i}{2}}$? If you consider $\abs{\frac{i}{2}}=||\frac{i}{2}||$ then you are right. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, it is true. The standard norm in complex numbers is defined as $\|a+bi\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and we have $\left\|{i\over 2}\right\| = {1\over 2}$.

Comment: Sorry, for my bad reply at first.

Comment: I'm glad we've come to understanding!

Comment: So what you are saying is norm and absolute values are the same in $\mathbb{C}$. But I think absolute value in $\mathbb{C}$ is not defined.

Comment: It is not my attitude my bad English again sorry.

Comment: It depends on what do you call an absolute value. From my experience, it is usually either a synonym to general norm or concretely the norm in $\mathbb{R}$. Anyway, it's better to talk about norm when convergence in general normed spaces is considered.

Comment: The answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Separate even and odd powers,

$$I=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\frac{i}{2})^n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{i}{2})^{2k} +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{i}{2})^{2k+1} =(1+\frac{i}{2}) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{i}{2})^{2k} = (1+\frac{i}{2}) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{-1}{4})^{k} $$

Now use sum of geometric series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{-1}{4})^{k} = \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{4})}-1=-\frac{1}{5}$$

Finally

$$I=(1+\frac{i}{2})(-\frac{1}{5})=-\frac{1}{5} -\frac{i}{10}$$

Comment: Separating into two sums is unnecessary complication, and is not related to the actual error in the question.

Comment: Yes. The method you followed is more beautiful.